# Unknown command 'pod' in directory /

Tags: ios, terminal, cocoapods

Why I can't use cocoapods command `pod` in directory /

```
/ $ pod
fish: Unknown command 'pod'
/ $
```

If use command in home directory, it work well.

```
~ $ pod
Usage:

    $ pod COMMAND

    CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.
```

Comment: macOS Sierra 10.12.5, fish shell

Comment: Does it work fine in the Bash shell?

Comment: Find the reason, my cocoapods install in chruby ruby 2.4, and .ruby-version file in home directory. So, the root directory not .ruby-version file, just use system base ruby, that not install cocoapods. So Unknown command error occur.

Comment: Nice ;) You should post an answer yourself (and accept it!) to also benefit future readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the reason, my cocoapods install in chruby ruby 2.4, and `.ruby-version` file in home directory.

So, the root directory not have `.ruby-version` file, just use system base ruby, that not install cocoapods. So Unknown command error occur.

At last, I copy my `~/.ruby-version` to `/.ruby-version`, it's work!